# How to turn my Android tablet into general Wifi IP camera with AP?

Tags: wi-fi, camera

I would like to turn my Android tablet into general Wifi IP camera to be accessible as a standard wifi camera from another wifi enabled tablet, smartphone or PC.

There is a number of Android apps on Google Play, called Wifi camera, but to stream video GSM connection is required and login to gmail on both devices is required either.

All I need is to have my tablet to act as a general WiFi camera , supporting wifi pairing
and access from VideoLan VLC media player via
rtsp (example rtsp://10.1.1.20:554/ch0_0.h264).

I want to stream not encrypted video   at a selected resolution ( HD or above)

2. I need such appl to come with AP, I can set multicast mode, to let 2 or more devices to access the same video stream
3. I am interested to have such Android appl to feature and support ONVIF wifi camera standard to let me run more ONVIF tests.

darius

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, 
What is AP ?

Do you only want Local Access ? 
Whereas the camera can only be connected to from the same WiFi network, Not publicly accessible ?

Or do you want Publicly Accessible ?
Whereas the camera can be accessed from another device remotely over the internet  ( check on home while you're at work for example )

You can create a simple IP Camera app that works on local networks very easily, however you'll need a server to handle internet access, I use [Ivideon](https://www.ivideon.com) to do my remote access.

My Setup ...

- [IP Webcam Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam.pro&hl=en)    ( For Running IP Camera )
- [TinyCam Monitor Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alexvas.dvr.pro)  ( For Viewing IP Cameras )
- [Ivideon Account](https://www.ivideon.com)  ( For Remote Camera Access )

Both TinyCam.. & IP Webcam .. Offer Free Versions.

Ivideon has a free limited account, the limits should be enough for Home use.

You can also grab some Free Open Sourced Alternative's from the website F-Droid [Free Open Sourced Software Repository F-Droid.org](http://f-droid.org)

---

**Part 2**

OK, so I've looked into IP WebCam and it uses it's own dedicated website that you can connect to locally, however I remember the app from a few years ago and behaved differently back then... Maybe Android limitations.

You can build an application for what you need, or search for RTSP Camera on Google Play,

I know that there is some because you can get libraries on GitHub that are OpenSourced .. like this one [pedroSG94's RTMP-RTSP-stream-client](https://github.com/pedroSG94/rtmp-rtsp-stream-client-java)

Comment: Thank you  for your answer.
AP stays for access point.
I am interested in direct connection over wifi, from PC, tablet or smartphone to my wifi enabled tablet, running WiFi IP camera app (Android 4.2.2)  Just installed IP Webcam on my tablet but no SSID is to be set to be brocasted over wifi to let me pair my PC with my tablet over wifi.

I am not interested in the cloud service since camera connection should work ad-hoc, locally.
My search for Wifi camera with F-Droid
https://search.f-droid.org/?q=Wifi+camera&lang=en generated no relevant app

Comment: follow-up
none results from search for IP Camera with your f-droid
https://search.f-droid.org/?q=ip+camera&lang=en

Comment: follow-up 2
TinyCam is monitor application for hardware IP cameras, so has nothing to do with my interest to have app installed on Android tablet to emulate real hardware IP camera ( wifi enabled) to let me connect to such tablet like to a real IP camera via UID SSID P2P wifi pairing

Comment: Their was several Open Sourced projects, however F-Droid was completely rebuilt and a lot of developers didn't re upload source's as required... Sorry about that link,  it is worth keeping an eye out..

Comment: thank you,
money is what makes developers happy ;)